# Reference frame(s) for return stroke of lightning bolts

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, lightning

A lightning bolt consists of two processes, one of them is slow -- the forward stroke, the other occurs at around a third of the speed of light $c$.

Each little part of the lightning bolt looks kind of like a straight line. Is there a way of aggregating the reference frames for each Lorenz contracted little bit into a larger frame?

Answer (score 0):

The straight-line segments of the (main channel) lightning bolt are called stepped leaders and are established during the slow progress of the forward stroke. This process creates the ion channel which then conducts the return stroke.

Because the conduction path for the return stroke exists in space before the return stroke takes place, and because it is possible to photograph the (non-relativistic) progress of the stepped leader and obtain a true account of those step lengths, it is not clear what you mean by the Lorentz contraction of the individual pieces of the return stroke.